# Python Quiz, how do I print this quiz/functions?

Tags: python, function, printing

I have made a questionnaire or short and easy math quiz for fun, with a little help from other forums.
I have questions as functions, with their answers inside them, eg:

```
def q1():
       print("What is 6 divided by 2?")
       answer = str(input())
       if answer == "3":
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
           print("CORRECT!")
       else:
           lives -= 1 # loses a life
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (loses a life)
           print("WRONG!")
       q1()
```

I have four of these questions, and they are **all inside one function:**

```
def questions():
   def q1():
       print("What is 6 divided by 2?")
       answer = str(input())
       if answer == "3":
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
           print("CORRECT!")
       else:
           lives -= 1 # loses a life
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (loses a life)
           print("WRONG!")
       q1()
       time.sleep(2)
       print()
   def q2():
       print("What is 6 multiplied by 2?")
       answer = str(input())
       if answer == "12":
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
           print("CORRECT!")
       else:
           lives -= 1 # loses a life
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (loses a life)
           print("WRONG!")
       q2()
       time.sleep(2)
       print()
   def q3():
       print("What is 5 multiplied by 5?")
       answer = str(input())
       if answer == "12":
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
           print("CORRECT!")
       else:
           lives -= 1 # loses a life
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (loses a life)
           print("WRONG!")
       q3()
       time.sleep(2)
       print()
   def q4():
       print("What is 20 divided by 2?")
       answer = str(input())
       if answer == "12":
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
           print("CORRECT!")
       else:
           lives -= 1 # loses a life
           print("You have {} lives left".format(lives)) # displays the current lives (loses a life)
           print("WRONG!")
       q4()
questions()
```

**My full code ^above^**
When I open the python interactive window, nothing is displayed or printed on the screen.

### How would I **print the def questions** and print if the player answered correct or incorrect?

Comment: Your only call to `q1` is _inside_ `q1`. Perhaps you intended your function calls to lie after the functions they are calling, instead of inside them.

Comment: You probably need to unindent the calls  `q1()` through to `q4()` by one level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would leave functions `q1` through `q4` outside the `questions` function, and inside the questions function you would simply type:

```
def questions():
    q1()
    q2()
    q3()
    q4()
```

and then at the bottom of the page you would call `questions()` just like you are doing already. The whole program would look something like:

```
def q1():
    print("What is 6 divided by 2?")
    answer = str(input())
    if answer == "3":
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
        print("CORRECT!")
    else:
        lives -= 1  # loses a life
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (loses a life)
        print("WRONG!")

def q2():
    print("What is 6 multiplied by 2?")
    answer = str(input())
    if answer == "12":
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
        print("CORRECT!")
    else:
        lives -= 1  # loses a life
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (loses a life)
        print("WRONG!")


def q3():
    print("What is 5 multiplied by 5?")
    answer = str(input())
    if answer == "12":
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
        print("CORRECT!")
    else:
        lives -= 1  # loses a life
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (loses a life)
        print("WRONG!")


def q4():
    print("What is 20 divided by 2?")
    answer = str(input())
    if answer == "12":
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (does not lose a life)
        print("CORRECT!")
    else:
        lives -= 1  # loses a life
        print("You have {} lives left".format(lives))  # displays the current lives (loses a life)
        print("WRONG!")

def questions():
        q1()
        time.sleep(2)
        q2()
        time.sleep(2)
        q3()
        time.sleep(2)
        q4()

questions()
```